# Should I consider quitting my Ph.D. after 6 months?

Tags: phd, quitting

About my background:

I finished my master's six months ago with a `cum laude` in Europe (A tier 1 university) and my research was very theoretical and I did invest a lot of thought into it. I like it a lot. Even though it was challenging, I was motivated. Therefore, I like to research a lot, I really do.

Because of my dedication, I was approached by my professor for a Ph.D. position. He listened to my interests and gave me some advice and some facts. According to him, people don't consider hiring people for a Ph.D. in the area I was interested in unless they have a solid background.

Then, he offered me a Ph.D. which is not related to what I did in my masters. I would say it is more applied than fundamental. I didn't do all courses related to that topic before to understand it fully. He promised to change the topic a little bit so that it fits my interests.

I did a literature review and I found questions to solve. He assigned me a daily supervisor who works under him. Let's call him DS (Daily Supervisor). I had heard not very good reviews about him earlier. People under him tend to finish their Masters and Ph.D. later than they originally are supposed to. He doesn't have a hold of concepts when it comes to research but at the same time has a lot of ideas that are scattered all over the place.

He confuses me all the time. When I came up with my research questions more towards my interests, he really tried forcing me to consider finding questions related to the more applied stuff and more towards its application side which is not my strong point because simply I don't have a solid background in it. Both the main professor and DS had some clash of ideas.

I am a direct person and if I don't like something I complain. They did find a direction for me and again promised that I would do something of my own interests after a year.

Now. I feel like I am trapped. My main professor is very considerate. I am thinking of asking him if I can do a post-masters here instead of a Ph.D. and do some TA work for the next six months and I will ask him to recommend me for some work abroad related to A for my next Ph.D.

The main professor still thinks I am creative, I have an analytical mind and also he trusts me. He may consider writing me a good recommendation. However, I may really hurt his trust that he has in me. Although I am really grateful I have this position and I can repay my loans, I am always in a position to complain. And, practically he reviews my results for the papers I want to write. It may affect it significantly and I wouldn't have any papers before I apply somewhere else.

I am really confused about what to do. The more I want to make the communication with my prof and DS transparent, the more they get me confused and I feel like a very bad student even though at the back of my head I know I was a `cum laude` student. Please give me your feedback on what you would do if you were me.

Comment: Only get a PhD if you really want to get a PhD.  Otherwise, don't.

Comment: Seems like this person would support you in applying to a wide range of PhD programs so you could make sure that you are going somewhere with the best match for your interests. When talking with them, make it about fit rather than personalities.

Comment: Depending on local customs, your main professor might be open to assigning you to a different daily supervisor, if the current match is not good.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, put aside your *cum laude* moniker. You are not in undergraduate anymore, you are in graduate school, and while you were miles ahead of your peers before, you now find yourself in a mix of your intellectual peers. This should be expected.

Second, there is no reason to be shy about raising your concerns in full disclosure to your advisor(s). The alternative is that you eventually leave anyway, so why not be brutally honest?

Your 'confusion' may stem from a lack of clear direction and path forward.  You can mitigate this by forcing yourself to write down you academic goals, and devise a plan to meet them, within reason given your advisors' interests and capabilities, of course.

Most of these things can be solved through communication; but unfortunately in higher academics communication can be difficult.

If you decide to go a different route, just make sure it is for *your* reasons and not those that are circumstantial.

Answer (score 6):

Based on my experience, there are a few points to consider before making your decision.

1. You do not need a solid background in a topic in order to conduct research on that topic. If what you studied during your master's degree is related to the research area, and also you are a promising potential PhD student, then you are also a good choice for an advisor.
2. Finishing your master's or PhD later than the standart study period is not necessarily a bad thing. Instead of this information, I would check whether the past students of DS have had good publications, got acceptance in good postdoctoral research programs etc. Ultimately, if you want to develop a career in academia, your best bet is to have strong publications instead of finishing your studies quickly.
3. Your research ideas are not mutually exclusive with your supervisors'. If you really want to conduct research on a topic, you can still do it. But if the topic that you want to work on is not related to the ongoing research project, then you cannot expect your advisors to drop their work and help you out. After all, they are paying you with the money they get from the funding, and they got that funding only because they promised to conduct research on a specific topic.
4. Being a good student does not necessarily mean being a good researcher. Yes, good researchers are generally good students, but there are many examples of world-class researchers being mediocre students, and vice-versa. You should not feel like a bad student, but maybe you should put some effort on being a better researcher.

I tried to be as generic as possible by giving examples from your situation. These are neither specific to your university nor to your advisors. If you believe that you can find *just the right research project* to participate in, then by all means, quit yesterday and start looking for that project. But I highly doubt it. Wherever you go, you will have to learn brand new things (theoretical or application) related to your master's studies.